# Import txt with macro using Excel?

Tags: excel

i would to import the last modified txt file from a directory using a macro in Excel.
I have a folder which is incremented everyday by a new txt file.
The goal is to import the last txt file added in the direrctory.

I've already created a an Excel file with a button affected to macro.

Here is the code of macro:

```
Sub Import()
'
' Import Macro
' Macro saved on 02/03/2011 by StYellowknife3000
'

'
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Folder\File_01.txt", Destination:= _
        Range("A1"))
        .Name = "File_01"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 932
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to use the Scripting.FileSystemObject and loop through all the files check their dates.  Here's some code I use to open the latest CSV in a folder

```
For Each fsoFile In fsoFldr.Files
    If fsoFile.DateCreated > dtNew And fsoFile.Type = sCSVTYPE Then
        sNew = fsoFile.Path
        dtNew = fsoFile.DateCreated
    End If
Next fsoFile

Workbooks.Open sNew
```

You can see all the code and the references you need to set here

http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2009/05/01/opening-the-newest-file-in-a-folder-with-vba/

Answer (score 0):

I found this example from another thread but it's working only if the filename is always same.
This one check the file with lastmodified but it's not working  as i want.

code:

```
Sub test()
MsgBox FileLastModified("C:\My Documents\abook.xls")
End Sub

Function FileLastModified(strFullFileName As String)
Dim fs As Object, f As Object, s As String

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fs.GetFile(strFullFileName)

s = UCase(strFullFileName) & vbCrLf
s = s & "Last Modified: " & f.DateLastModified
FileLastModified = s

Set fs = Nothing: Set f = Nothing

End Function
```